# Parameters.AddWithValue failing

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.data.sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm getting the "System.FormatException: The input has the wrong format." error on the second attempt while the first one works perfectly fine.

Does anybody see why this is so?

Attempt 1:

```
    Using nCmdIns1 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = cnUser.CreateCommand
        With nCmdIns1
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO images (oemimageguid,imagetitle,imagecategory,imagesize,imageblob256) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)"
            .Parameters.Add("@1", DbType.String).Value = uOEMImageGUID
            .Parameters.Add("@2", DbType.String).Value = uTitle
            .Parameters.Add("@3", DbType.Int32).Value = iCat
            .Parameters.Add("@4", DbType.Int32).Value = uImageSize
            .Parameters.Add("@5", DbType.Binary).Value = uBytes
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    End Using
```

Attempt 2:

```
    Using nCmdIns2 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = cnUser.CreateCommand
        With nCmdIns2
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO images (oemimageguid,imagetitle,imagecategory,imagesize,imageblob256) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", DbType.String).Value = uOEMImageGUID
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", DbType.String).Value = uTitle
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", DbType.Int32).Value = iCat
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", DbType.Int32).Value = uImageSize
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", DbType.Binary).Value = uBytes
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    End Using
```

I've tried to isolate the problem by removing parameters and values one by one, but in the end, I got the same error even with this sparse line:

```
    Using nCmdIns3 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = cnUser.CreateCommand
        With nCmdIns3
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO images (oemimageguid) VALUES (@1)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", DbType.String).Value = uOEMImageGUID
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    End Using
```

Here is a screenshot of the exception for attempt 3:

[image]

Comment: The second parameter of AddWithValue is the Value itself, not the type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx in any case try to use always the first method because you have more control on the type of the parameter

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clarification. But when can I add a ").Value" after "AddWithValue"?

Comment: You can because the Add method returns the Parameter and value is a property of the parameter.

Comment: Also a GUID is not a string...wee cant tell what those vars are though

Comment: I made it a string because some generators / API functions return braces, some don't, it was so scary that I decided to make it a string field.

Comment: If something returns a curly brace it is returning a string not a GUID, but if it represents a legitimate GUID it can be parsed.

Comment: I'm using the API function StringFromGUID2. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of AddWithValue is the Value itself, not the type

See MSDN [AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

In any case try to use always the first method because you have more control on the type of the parameter.

[Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
Using nCmdIns2 As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = cnUser.CreateCommand
    With nCmdIns2
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO images (oemimageguid,imagetitle,imagecategory,imagesize,imageblob256) VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5)"
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", uOEMImageGUID)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", uTitle)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", iCat)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", uImageSize)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", uBytes)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
End Using
```